# Understanding function calls in ARM ASM

Tags: android, c++, assembly, android-ndk, arm

I am disassemblying native Android libraries (armeabi-v7a) which were most likely created from C++ or C code and are stripped.
The target is to create a function call tree for later analysis.

I have issues understanding the disassembled output.

Take the following assembler snippet created by `arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -d libledger.so > output.txt`

```
00014988 <_ZSt10__pop_heapIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEENS0_5__ops15_Iter_less_iterEEvT_S9_S9_T0_>: 
   ...
   149e0:   4620        mov r0, r4
   149e2:   f030 fadd   bl  44fa0 <_ZNK10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_info11__do_upcastEPKNS_17__class_type_infoEPKvRNS1_15__upcast_resultE+0x2a7ec>
   149e6:   e7ff        b.n 149e8 <_ZSt10__pop_heapIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEENS0_5__ops15_Iter_less_iterEEvT_S9_S9_T0_+0x60>
   149e8:   4628        mov r0, r5
   149ea:   f030 fad9   bl  44fa0 <_ZNK10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_info11__do_upcastEPKNS_17__class_type_infoEPKvRNS1_15__upcast_resultE+0x2a7ec>
   149ee:   f004 fe55   bl  1969c <__cxa_end_cleanup>
   149f2:   bf00        nop
   149f4:   b154        cbz r4, 14a0c <_ZSt16__introsort_loopIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEiNS0_5__ops15_Iter_less_iterEEvT_S9_T0_T1_+0x14>
   149f6:   0005        movs    r5, r0

000149f8 <_ZSt16__introsort_loopIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEiNS0_5__ops15_Iter_less_iterEEvT_S9_T0_T1_>:
   149f8:   e92d 4ff0   stmdb   sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, lr}
   149fc:   1d07        adds    r7, r0, #4
   149fe:   b085        sub sp, #20
   14a00:   4604        mov r4, r0
   14a02:   4690        mov r8, r2
   14a04:   460e        mov r6, r1
   14a06:   1b35        subs    r5, r6, r4
   14a08:   2d43        cmp r5, #67 ; 0x43
   14a0a:   f340 8095   ble.w   14b38 <_ZSt16__introsort_loopIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEiNS0_5__ops15_Iter_less_iterEEvT_S9_T0_T1_+0x140>
   14a0e:   f1b8 0f00   cmp.w   r8, #0
   14a12:   d13f        bne.n   14a94 <_ZSt16__introsort_loopIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEiNS0_5__ops15_Iter_less_iterEEvT_S9_T0_T1_+0x9c>
   14a14:   10ad        asrs    r5, r5, #2
   14a16:   4b4a        ldr r3, [pc, #296]  ; (14b40 <_ZSt16__introsort_loopIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPSsSt6vectorISsSaISsEEEEiNS0_5__ops15_Iter_less_iterEEvT_S9_T0_T1_+0x148>)
   14a18:   1eaf        subs    r7, r5, #2
   14a1a:   f10d 090c   add.w   r9, sp, #12
```

Of the branch instructions described [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/Chddgiff.html) those of the `BL` family resemble most a function call, which is also hinted at [5.3 Subroutine Call](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042e/IHI0042E_aapcs.pdf).
Then there are also system calls via `SWI`.
Yet some questions arise to me:

1. Can I be sure for the `BL` instructions that the labels to jump to always point to the beginning of a C-function? This would mean that they act like calling a C-function.
2. What other instructions are used for C-function calls?
3. In the example above it would mean at `149e2:` there is a function call. I don't understand the `<XY+0x2a7ec>` part though.
   Does that mean that ...

   - The called function starts at `addressoff(XY) + 0x2a7ec`, but is not in the `.dynsym` table and thus has no human-friendly name for the disassembler to refer to?
   - Does it mean that `XY` is called with a huge offset into its body?
   - Or are both possible?
4. How do I recognise the start of functions? To me it looks like the parts with complete addresses like `00014988 <...>` are functions. Though I fear that this only works for functions that are part of the dynamic symbols table, which would explain the huge offsets above.
5. At `149f4` there also is a branch, this time via `CBZ`. This also looks like a function call into a different function, and again with an offset. When both `00014988` and `000149f8` are functions when this `CBZ` call would jump directly into the function and not at the beginning. What does this mean?

Comment: 1. For compiler generated code, pretty much yes. 2. Can also branch (tail call) 3. Presumably no symbol 4. That's hard ;)  5. That is unreachable code since __cxa_end_cleanup never returns. It's either data or just garbage for alignment.

Comment: Use -C to demangle C++ methods. If this is for professional purposes use IDA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I be sure for the BL instructions that the labels to jump to always point to the beginning of a C-function? This would mean that they act like calling a C-function.

Yes, most of the time the branch will be to the beginning of the function.

> What other instructions are used for C-function calls?

Anything that can change the program counter.
I've see `BX, LDR PC,` and `POP` instructions.

> In the example above it would mean at 149e2: there is a function call. I don't understand the  part though. Does that mean that ...
>   The called function starts at addressoff(XY) + 0x2a7ec, but is not in the .dynsym table and thus has no human-friendly name for the disassembler to refer to?

Not every address aligns with a sourced line number.  The offset is the distance from a known symbol in the *map* file, usually a function name.

> Does it mean that XY is called with a huge offset into its body?

No.  The destination of the branch is at an offset from a *public* symbol.  There are many cases where a lot of functions are not public, so they are referenced to the nearest public symbol in the map file.

> Or are both possible?

See above.

> How do I recognise the start of functions?

There is no general rule.
Here is a process:

1. Open up the listing file (that contains the assembly language).
2. Look for the offset within the assembly language listing.
3. Or find the fundtion, then add the offset and look for that address.

> At 149f4 there also is a branch, this time via CBZ. This also looks like a function call into a different function, and again with an offset. When both 00014988 and 000149f8 are functions when this CBZ call would jump directly into the function and not at the beginning. What does this mean?

The `CBZ` is not a *subroutine* or *function* call.  It is a branch to another address.  No return is expected.

The Branch and Link (`BL`) and Branch and Exchange (`BX`) instructions set the `LR` register to a return address (usually the next instruction after `BL` or `BX`).  In order to return, the value in the `LR` register is copied into the Program Counter (`PC`) register, causing execution to transfer to the address in LR.  This is a return from the function or subroutine call.

Comment: Note that the `cbz` isn't even a branch in this context, it's clearly just some data that happens to look like a conditional branch instruction by chance - its 'target' is not just the middle of a function (bypassing the prologue which would unbalance the stack), but the middle of another _instruction_. No compiler is ever going to emit code that mad.

Comment: BLX modifies LR, not BX.  And yes bl sets lr to the address after the bl instruction.

Comment: "How do I recognise the start of functions?" push {...}/stmdb   sp!, {...} are good indicators. In most cases function preserves registers at first place & restores them before returning.